# What is the Stochastic Differential Equation representation of a Poisson Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

What is the Stochastic Differential Equation representation of a Poisson Process?

Can it be expressed as a function of $dW$ where $W$ is a Wiener process?

Answer (score 1):

No, as the sample paths are constant between arrivals. Of course, one could say it is a Poisson jump process model with degenerate brownian diffusion (variance = 0)...but that's just being contrived.